# How to get Text from Textbox created during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created WinForm App in which user can set how many textboxes he want (Range 1-99)
I am using this code to create Textboxes during runtime

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Calculation.Num; i++)
   {
       TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
       txtRun.Name = "txtBox" + i;
       txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 50 + (20 * i) * 2);
       txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
       this.Controls.Add(txtRun);                
   }
```

Suppose user create 2 textboxes and then enter data in each textbox and click calculate button
Now i want to **get the textboxes data** and divide it by 100

See The Picture I want txtbox1 and txtbox2 data

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

This is the Whole Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GPA_Calculatior__New_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int j = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Label + Marks Obtained Textbox
            for (int i = 0; i < Calculation.Num; i++)
            {
                Label lblCount = new Label();
                lblCount.Name = "lblCount" + i;
                lblCount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 55 + (20 * i) * 2);
                lblCount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 30);
                lblCount.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(lblCount);

                TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
                txtRun.Name = "txtBox" + i;
                txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 50 + (20 * i) * 2);
                txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
                this.Controls.Add(txtRun);   

            }

            //Creating Textbox which is for total marks
            for (j = 0; j < Calculation.Num; j++)
            {
                TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
                txtRun.Name = "TotaltxtBox" + j;
                txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 50 + (20 * j) * 2);
                txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
                txtRun.Text = "100";
                txtRun.Enabled = false;
                this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
            }
            // Creating 2 Buttons (Calculate and Back)
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                Button Btn = new Button();
                Btn.Name = "btn" + k;
                Btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (k *110), 60 + (20 * j) * 2);
                Btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 30);

                if (k == 0)               
                    Btn.Text = "Back";

                else
                    Btn.Text = "Calculate";

                Btn.Click += button_Click;

                this.Controls.Add(Btn);
            }

            //Just for Giving free space in last

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + j;
            lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 90 + (20 * j) * 2);
            lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 30);
            lbl.Text = "";

            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            //**********************************************
        }

        //Caculate and back button function
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            if (btn.Name.Equals("btn1"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Calculation.Num; i++)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                GPA_Calculator mainForm = new GPA_Calculator();
                mainForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            } 
        }




        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {

            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var sum = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(t => char.IsDigit(t.Name.Reverse().Take(1).FirstOrDefault())
        && t.Enabled)
    .Select(t =>
    {
        double i;
        if (!double.TryParse(t.Text, out i)) { return 0d; }
        return i / 100d;
    })
    .Sum();
```

Comment: Sorry for say that i dont understand any thing for code above
it's a little bit complex
is there any easy way to do that and besides i want to divide each textbox data with 100

Comment: Imho, he should just store references to the textboxes. There may be more numerical textboxes on the form down the road that are irrelevant.

Comment: It gets all numerical textboxes in your grid and then tries to get a double out of it and then divides the sum of all the textboxes by 100. Res stores your answer @UzairAli

Comment: Maybe better to build a List<> to store them so they remain independent of the rest of the form

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'char'
The best overloaded method match for 'char.IsDigit(char)' has some invalid argumentsor (New)

Comment: Take(1) is probably returning an IEnumerable of char

Comment: @UzairAli, please see my edit to resolve the enumerable error.

Comment: The program runs fine but answer is not coming right when i enter 90 and calculate it shows 1.9 sum is 190 why 1 is adding in front of every number

Comment: Actually your code is adding all textbox numbers (including disabled textboxes) and then divide by 100 I want to divide each textbox by 100 (Not include Disabled textboxes these are just for show)

Comment: @UzairAli, I've modified the code to excluded disabled text boxes and sum up the individual divisions.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, I built a separate class to store the control and its value, then you can work out the values independently from the rest of the form. You need to trigger the calculations though:

```
    private List<InfoTextBox> activeTextBoxes = new List<InfoTextBox>();
    public Form1()
    {         
        for (int i = 0; i < Calculation.Num; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "txtBox" + i;
            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 50 + (20 * i) * 2);
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
            InfoTextBox iBox = new InfoTextBox();
            iBox.textbox = txtRun;
            activeTextBoxes.Add(iBox);
        }
    }

    public class InfoTextBox
{
    private double _textboxValue;
    public TextBox textbox { get; set; }
    public double TextBoxValue { get { return _textboxValue; } set { _textboxValue = setValue(value); } }

    private double setValue(double invalue)
    {
        return invalue / 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use an auto-implemented property for TextBoxValue ?

Comment: Yes you can, it would be of use if you masked the keypresses to numeric values and send the update to the TextBoxValue